# Session timeout vs Form Authentication timeout

Tags: asp.net, authentication

What is the difference between a abandon Session and a cookie timeout, what if the session is abandon and the cookie is still alive, is that can lead to a problem?

```
<sessionState timeout="1" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="1" />
</authentication>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that leads to a problem.  Session timeout is specific to the session state mechanism, but for forms, the timeout is specific to the cookie that retains the user's credentials.

In an app of mine, the user is still logged in as the session times out, but once the auth cookie times out, the user has to log in again.

HTH.

Comment: What happens to the information in the session, in that case?  The user log in while the system expects information in the session.

Comment: In one of my apps, I had to explicitly abandon the session via Session.Abandon on logout, because it was keeping the session...  The system shouldn't always expect something to be in the session; handling nulls gracefully is a good thing when it comes to session.